# How to declare generic base class?

Tags: swift, generics, uiviewcontroller

I have a case which is:

`class BaseMvpController<V, P: BasePresenter>: UIViewController  { }`

I need to make the base class to be of generic type instead of  `UIViewController`.

At some point, I need it to be `UIViewController , UITableViewController` ..etc

for Example :

My Base Class

```
class BaseMvpController<V, P: BasePresenter>: UIViewController  {
    typealias View = V
    private(set) var presenter: P!
    // MARK: - Initializers

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override public init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }

    deinit {
        guard let view = self as? P.View else {return}
        if let presenter = presenter {
            presenter.detachView(view)
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter = createPresenter()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let view = self as? P.View else {
            preconditionFailure("MVP ViewController must implement the view protocol `\(View.self)`!")
        }

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if !presenter.isAttached {
            presenter.attachView(view)
        }
    }
    // MARK: - MVP

    /// Override and return a presenter in a subclass.
    func createPresenter() -> P {
        preconditionFailure("MVP method `createPresenter()` must be override in a subclass and do not call `super.createPresenter()`!")
    }

}
```

My **AController**

`class AController : BaseMvpController <AView, APresenter> { }`

> If we thought it was a kind of UIViewController its works normally

My **BController**

`class BController : BaseMvpController <AView, APresenter> { }`

> If we thought it was a kind of `UITableViewController`, This is case I can not  override `numberOfItemInRaw` and dequeCell ...etc , because base controller inherit from `UIViewController`

I want to make Base controller works with all controller (`UIViewController`, `UITableViewController`, `UICollectionViewController` .. etc).

How can i do this

Comment: You can’t. UIViewController is not a generic.

Comment: @matt Thanks , do you think there is any workaround to achieve it.

Comment: Perhaps consider extending UIViewController instead.

Comment: You have not explained what “it” is. This is an xy question. Ask about your real problem, not some fake solution.

Comment: @matt my question edited please check it

Comment: You still can’t do it. You cannot unify or genericise Cocoa Objective C classes in Swift. If it were possible people would already have done it.

Comment: @a.masri can you share your  BasePresenter

Comment: You don't have to use `UICollectionViewController` or `UITableViewController`. Just add a `UICollectionView` or `UITableView` views. If you really want to use those controllers, you can add them as child controller to your base controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'hide' generic inside another class.

E.g.,

```
class Generic<T, U> { }
class BV: UIViewController {
    var generic: Generic<Int, String>? = nil
}
```